# How to Customize json? How can override WriteToStreamAsync method in the MediaTypeFormatter for the customization of json Result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, jsonserializer, mediatypeformatter

I have a webApi Application which is a migration from an existing Api, as per client need json and xml result (which is specified within the URL `http://localhost:1518/api/List?type=regions&format=json`), So In my application i have a class for xml and json result

```
public class ContinentData
{
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("response_item")]
public class ContinentsList
{
  [XmlArray("regions")]
  [XmlArrayItem("region")]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "regions")]
  public List<ContinentData> Region { get; set; }
  public ContinentsList()
  {
    Region = new List<ContinentData>();
  }
}
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Continents
{
  [XmlElement("response_item")]
  public ContinentsList Regions { get; set; }
  public Continents()
  {
    Regions = new ContinentsList();
  }
}
```

and I get the xml output,

```
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <response_item>
  <regions>
   <region>
    <id>AFRICA</id>
    <name>Africa</name>
   </region>
  </response_item>
 </response>
```

which is fine, but for the json result i get

```
{"Regions":{"regions":[{"id":"AFRICA","name":"Africa"}]}}
```

But what i really want `[{"regions":[{"id":"AFRICA","name":"Africa"}]}]`I think that there is one class less for the json results. All of my json result is like that.So I try to customize by creating a customJsonFormatter class and Overrides WriteToStreamAsync method in the MediaTypeFormatter class, I do not know this is right method, but i try

```
 public class CustomJsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{

    public CustomJsonFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == (Type)null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value,
        Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content,
        System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
            {

               // logic here
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
                writeStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                writeStream.Flush();
            });

        return task;
    }
}
```

The Global.asax file

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
         new QueryStringMapping("format", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new QueryStringMapping("format", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true; 

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new CustomJsonFormatter());
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
   }
```

While run the application and I get the xml result as default if the format is json in the URL, and also not hit on WriteToStreamAsync method in the customJsonFormatter class. How can I do this? Is this proper way? Suggest solution for this

Answer (score 0):

For the xml case you get your xml formatted to add response_item tag by using the XmlElement attribute. Similarly to work with Newtonsoft (assuming from the serializer syntax) you can your Json specific attribute.

```
[JsonProperty("response_item")]
[XmlElement("response_item")]
public ContinentsList Regions { get; set; }
```

Over the property Regions.